# Is there a way to view cookies in Opera, Safari and Internet Explorer

Tags: browser, plugins, cookies

In Firefox, if you have the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/addon/60) plugin installed you can view the cookies a particular site has setup in the browser.

Is there a way/plugin to do that in another of the other browsers?

Comment: It's a shame your question is so broad instead of just the one browser. Most answers are going to be one or the other.

Comment: Well think of it this way, if people post a bunch of different answers for each browser then some smart person can compile them all and I'll mark that one as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CookieSpy](http://www.cookiespy.com) is a free tool to view IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera cookies.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In Opera it is built-in, and you have two choices. The first is to use the super-useful site preferences dialog (found in the context menu):

[image]

The second is to use the cookie manager (*Tools* → *Advanced* → *Cookies*...), which lists every site and every cookie; you can quick search through it easily too.

With either method every cookie value is editable, so you can easily hack your cookies:

[image]

I also setup a custom mouse gesture where I draw a C on a page and I trigger a JavaScript function to show me the cookies in a dialog - **this JavaScript should be usable on any browser**:

```
javascript:alert('Cookies stored by this host or domain:\n\n' + document.cookie.replace(/; /g,'\n'));
```